# An idiomatic German translation of the Bible

Tags: idiom, book

Is there a translation of at least the New Testament into German which uses modern vocabulary and idioms, similarly to the way [The Message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Message_%28Bible%29) does in English?

Comment: Never heard of *The Message*. Very interesting question.

Comment: There are a lot of modern Bible translations. Google for modern Bible translations: Moderne Bibelübersetzungen.

Answer (score 6):

There is a contemporary translation of The Bible done by the [*"Gute Nachricht"*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gute-Nachricht-Bibel) project. The translation is available as print or [online](http://www.die-bibel.de/online-bibeln/gute-nachricht-bibel/bibeltext/) (free). At the online portal you will also find various other translations including Luther's.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that is what you are looking for, but there is a project called volxbibel, which is a translation done in form of a wiki under the creative commons license.
Which is an interesting idea.

The language is very atypical to a bible and quite modern.

AFAIK the whole thing is controversial, because the language may not be accurate in some places or is regarded to be inappropriate for a bible.

To learn more you can visit the [website](http://www.volxbibel.de/) of the project or read the German article on [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volxbibel), which contains some pro and cons along other information.

Comment: An interesting project! Makes me wonder if Luther would be interested in running a wiki if the technology was available at that time.